# Laravel Ajax subtotal only changing for one product, and not working for multiple products

Tags: ajax, laravel

This is a shopping cart, quantity will be multiplied with the price to show subtotal, when i only input one item in the cart, it works, but when i input multiple items it gives this error.
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'quantity' cannot be null (SQL: update `carts` set `quantity` = ?)"

I believe its from this  $("#qty").change(function(e) Id taking one item, but im not sure, help will be highly appreciated

blade:

```
<tr>
    <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="#"><img style="object-fit: contain;" src="{{asset('product-images/'.$product->image)}}" alt=""  width="200px" height="120px"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="product-name">{{$product->title}}</td>
    <td class="product-price-cart"><span class="amount" id="price">{{$product->price}} </span> $</td>
    <td class="product-quantity ">
        <div class="cart-plus-minus ">
            <input class="cart-plus-minus-box qty" type="number" id="qty" class="qty" name="qty" value="1" >
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="product-subtotal" id="subtotal"><span class="subtotal">{{$product->price}} </span>$ </td>

    <td>
    <form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cart->id)}}" method="POST" >
        @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

    </form>

</td>
</tr>
```

script in blade:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#qty").change(function(e){
        
e.preventDefault();
var selct_ = $(this) //declare this
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
    $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('checkout.qty') }}", 
    data:{
    'quantity':qty.value
    }, 
    type: "get",
    success: function(result){
     var price=selct_.closest('tr').find('.amount').text();
     console.log(price);
     $('.subtotal').text(result[0]*price);
    }
  });
});
});
```

Controller

```
public  function quantity(Request $request){
DB::table('carts')->update(
['quantity'=> $request->quantity]
);
return response()->json([$request->quantity,200]); 
}
```

[image: sample picture]

Answer (score 0):

qty is not defined. Try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#qty").change(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var qty = e.target;


        var selct_ = $(this) //declare this
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
            $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('checkout.qty') }}", 
            data:{
                    'quantity':qty.value
            }, 
            type: "get",
            success: function(result){
            var price=selct_.closest('tr').find('.amount').text();
            console.log(price);
            $('.subtotal').text(result[0]*price);
           }
        });
      });
   });
```

Comment: Now when i have 2 products, and change the qty of the first product, the subtotal of the first and second item are changing, $('.subtotal').text(result[0]*price); should be changed maybe?

Comment: Yes, with "$('.subtotal').text(result[0]*price);" you are updating all items that have a class  ".subtotal"